# Safely remove USB device (of any type, not only block devices/mass storage)?

Tags: linux, usb

There are some questions on U&L that ask about how to correctly remove an USB device from Linux box, implicitly meaning a block device, having been in used via a mounted filesystem on top of it.

Well, there are other USB devices also, and I wanted to ask about the more general case. Let's say I wanted to remove an USB webcam gadget from my Linux box. Is the correct/safe way to simply write to issue a
finale:

```
$ echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/<device-addr>/remove
```

**NOTE:** I have noticed that with usb-mass-storage devices, I can "remove" the power via the command above, even though they have not been unmounted. The mount point remains and access to it results in `Input/output error`s
which seems to indicate that also for other type of USB devices (e.g. the webcam gadget) I might need to first remove loaded kernel (i.e. via `rmmod`) or otherwise deactivate the device to be removed?

Comment: What makes you think a non-storage device needs manual removal of the driver/module and/or manual "deactivation" ? There is no  risk of data loss or corruption so where is the problem ? What exactly is "unsafe" if you just unplug the device ?

Comment: @don_crissti your hint that USB unplugging (least for data loss in storage devices) is always safe to the hardware/os is based on your knowledge about the RFC/standards/norms of USB? If so I would be glad to accept an answer that hints that mere unplugging is safe, citing ideally the USB standard that says so, if you can find it more swiftly than I can.

Comment: It's common sense, there's no need to read the standards to understand that no one in their right mind would design an OS / peripherals that need a "safely remove" feature before unplugging stuff like a USB mouse, keyboard, camera, whatever... There is nothing unsafe as there's no data that would be lost or corrupted.

Comment: I second this question. @don_crissti: That's not common sense, if there's a USB routed device that overheats or use power that I can't remove (e.g. webcam, controllers, etc), it does makes sense to be able to shut it down even if the kernel don't hook it up since some of these device do have their own ways (thanks OEMs) and still use power.